# Internal Salesforce.com error when deleting OpportunityShare records

Tags: apex

I am deleting OpportunityShare records with following code in my developer console

```
List<OpportunityShare> osList = [Select opportunityid from OpportunityShare  where UserOrGroupId = '00GG000000XXXXXXXX' And Rowcause = 'Manual'];
delete(osList);
```

The above list has 7400 records and on execution I am getting **Internal Salesforce.com Error**.This is error is shown debug log of developer console.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the internal Salesforce.com error?  Please edit the question and add the error you are getting and where you see it (e.g., debug log in dev console, alert box from dev console, etc.).

Comment: It just says Internal Salesforce.com error in dev console debug log

Comment: can you try with lesser number of records?? 1000 at a time

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you get an internal salesforce error, something very bad happened in the underlying code.  You're options are 1) Send the error id to Salesforce and request the underlying cause (which can often make troubleshooting it very straightforward), or 2) Try anything and everything to work around it.

In your case I'd recommend trying to delete just one opportunity share first and see if that works.  If it doesn't try manually deleting the opportunity share via the sharing page and see if you get a nicer error there.  If it does, you might trying using a binary search technique to see if there is one particular record that is causing the error and just skip that one.